# Transform files for NuGet package class library project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I've created a project of type "Class Library (Package)" with Visual Studio 2015.

How am I supposed to add a web/app config transform file to the NuGet package?

Answer (score 0):

Add a file to your project called: **App.config.install.xdt**

In your .nuspec file add:

```
<files>
    <file src="App.config.install.xdt" target="content\App.config.install.xdt" />
</files>
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx

The following example shows the contents of a transform file that changes a connection string and replaces the customErrors element

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDB" 
      connectionString="value for the deployed Web.config file" 
      xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm"
      mode="RemoteOnly" xdt:Transform="Replace">
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Note a ".transform' file, is needed if you want to add a file NOT called app.config.